# RxJS Observable - attach Subject consumer on subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an Angular service which keeps an private `BehaviorSubject` so that it can read the value at any given time.  It is private so that any component that uses it cannot manipulate it.  Instead, a regular `Observable` is exposed as public.  The `BehaviorSubject` is now a consumer of any data emitted by this observable.

```
public subheaderData$: Observable<SubheaderData>;
private subheaderDataSubject$: BehaviorSubject<SubheaderData> = new BehaviorSubject<SubheaderData>(null);

constructor(private repository: SubHeaderRepository) {
    this.subheaderData$ = this.load();
    this.subheaderData$.subscribe(this.subheaderDataSubject$);
}
```

As you can see, I am calling `.subscribe` from my service, which makes my observable hot immediately.  What I would like to accomplish is that a component which injects this service must subscribe to the public `Observable`, and when that happens, the `BehaviorSubject` should automatically be added as an observer, even though the component has no knowledge of it (due to it being private.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: So you want `subheaderDataSubject$` to subscribe to `subheaderData$` only when there's at least one subscriber to `subheaderDataSubject$`?

Comment: @martin - When the component subscribes to `subheaderData$` which is in the service, I want the service to attach the `subheaderDataSubject$` as an observer.

Comment: So when someone subscribes to `subheaderData$` it should automatically subscribe `this.subheaderDataSubject$` to `subheaderData$`.

Comment: @martin yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your service constructor

```
this.subheaderData$ = this.subheaderDataSubject$.asObservable();
```

then subscribe to `subheaderData$` whenever needed

and you can `this.subheaderDataSubject$.next(someValue)` in your service

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not missing anything critical I think you should be able to accomplish what you want only by using `multicast` even though this will be a little unusual use-case.

```
subheaderDataPublic$ = this.subheaderData$.pipe(
  multicast(this.subheaderDataSubject$, s => s),
);
```

Then in your component you'll subscribe to `subheaderDataPublic$`.

Typically, you'd use `multicast` for example like this:

```
multicast(new Subject(), s => merge(s, s.pipe(...)))
```

... but if you pass it `this.subheaderDataSubject$` it'll be used as an intermediate Subject. That `s => s` above is required because without any selector function `multicast` returns an instance of `ConnectableObservable` which is probably something you don't need.

EDIT: Maybe a better understandable solution would be using just `Observable` constructor.

```
subheaderDataPublic$ = new Observable(observer => {
  const subscriptions = new Subscription();
  subscriptions.add(this.subheaderData$.subscribe(this.subheaderDataSubject$));
  subscriptions.add(this.subheaderDataSubject$.subscribe(observer));

  return () => subscriptions.unsubscribe();
});
```